# Displaying scraped data in chart with chart.js and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

i want to create a chart of wind data.
however the chart shows up blank.

the scraping function works fine on its own but the chart does not seem to be able to get the data properly.

How do i make sure the chart function has got the right data?

my code is below.

Thank you.

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const WindChart = () =>
{
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})
    let winds = []
    request(
        'https://www.bmreports.com/bmrs/?q=generation%2Ffueltype&fbclid=IwAR2p2a84CaJhgzF-YOU4MzOS-cMuZUpeDmLHFkWZU7-NauRHrA1owwdsMog',
        (error, response, html) =>
        {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200)
            {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);

                 winds = $('.gen-fuel tbody td:nth-child(8)')
                    .map(function ()
                    {
                        return $(this).text();
                    })
                    .get();


            }
        }
    )
    const chart = () =>
    {

        setChartData({
            labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Wind Power',
                    data: winds,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(75,192,192,0.1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 10
                }
            ]
        })

    }
    useEffect(() =>
    {
        chart()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Wind Stuff</h1>
            <div> <Line data={chartData} /> </div>
        </div>
    )

}
export default WindChart;
```

Comment: To simplify, first find out where it’s broken (bad props going into Line? Or something else?). Instead of outputting the Line component under the H1, dump part of the data to see if it’s populating.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the chart implementation, try to add any values for winds, eg `winds = [2,5,3,6]` and you'll see the line on the chart. Make sure the cheerio returns the values you expect

Comment: @Hani when i fill the array with dummy data it works fine. i've also tested the scraping in a seperat file and that works fine as well. The problem seems to be that the changes made to the winds array are not passe along. also i get this message React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'chart'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps –

Comment: @AlanP. not sure i understand what you mean by dumping the data?

Comment: Instead of `<div> <Line data={chartData} /> </div>` put `<div>{JSON.stringify(chartData);}</div>` so you can see if the variable is correct.

Comment: @AlanP. i found out that the site blocks CORS. so i have to solve that first. 
thanks though